# How to apply CIFilter to CGImageRef?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cifilter, cgimageref

I tried to apply a `CIFilter` to a `CGImageRef`, but it seems not to work this way.

```
CGImageRef image = _image;
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName @"CISephiaTone" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, image, @"inputItensity", @0.8, nil];
CGImageRef outputImage = (__bridge CGImageRef)([filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey]);
```

Does anyone know how I can apply a filter to an image reference and deliver the output image to a drawRect method?

I tried also `CGImageRef outputImage = [filter outputImage]`. But `outputImage` isn't known by the compiler?

Comment: What do you mean with "it seems not to work" ? And did you really write in your program **@"CISephiaTone"** ? Such a filter does not exist! The correct name is **@"CISepiaTone"**.

Comment: @heinrich Yep you are right, of cause I mean @"CISepiaTone". After execution the program breaks =(

Comment: Might it be easier to create a `CALayer` with that filter effect and then add that layer over your image?